# Is cardano-cli 1.35.3's calculate-min-required-utxo underestimating?

Tags: cardano-cli, mint

For minting a token, I compute the minimum amount as follows:

```
cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-required-utxo 
  --babbage-era                                     
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json   
  --tx-out "addr_test⋯pxzl 2000000 + 1 019b⋯55f5.766963"
```

This gives "Lovelace 1021470", which I'd plug into the `--tx-out` expression of the 'transaction build' command like this:

```
cardano-cli transaction build
  --testnet-magic 1
  --tx-in-collateral 3a0d⋯84af#3
  --tx-in 3a0d⋯84af#3
  --tx-in 616c⋯3486#1
  --tx-in f029⋯d21b#3
  --tx-out "addr_test⋯pxzl 1021470 + 1 019b⋯55f5.766963"
  --mint "1 019b⋯55f5.766963"
  --change-address addr_test⋯pxzl
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json
  --minting-script-file policy.script
  --out-file unsigned.json
```

But with cardano-cli 1.35.3, this gives me:

```
"Command failed: transaction build Error: Minimum UTxO threshold not met for tx output: 
addr_test⋯pxzl + 1021470 lovelace + 1 019b⋯55f5.766963"
Minimum required UTxO: Lovelace 1344720
```

The above procedure used to work perfectly with older cardano-cli 's (last one tested: cardano-cli-1.34.1)

Question: Is cardano-cli 1.35.3's calculate-min-required-utxo **underestimating**, or is there a **new way** to compute the min-required-utxo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `calculate-min-required-utxo`  with `--babbage-era` flag and `build` without any era flag. cardano-node 1.34.3 defaults to Alonzo-era.

There appears to be a bug for overestimation in this scenario: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/4297

Use `--babbage-era` for both cmds.